# Code produces no output java

Tags: java, printing

Im trying to write a code, that computes CD value, for every month. 
Suppose you put **10,000** dollars into a CD with an annual percentage yield of **6,15%**.
After one month the CD is worth:

**10000 + 10000 * 6,15 / 1200 = 10051.25**

After the next month :

**10051.25 + 10051.25 * 6,15 / 1200 = 10102.76**

Now I need to display all the results for the specific number of months entered by the user, 
So

**month1 =**

**month2 =**

But whth this code I wrote, nothing is printed.
Can you see what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CDValue {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an amount");
    double amount = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println ("Enter the annual percentage yield");
    double percentage = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println ("Enter the number of months");
    int months = input.nextInt();

    double worth = amount + amount * percentage / 1200;

    for (int i = 1; i < months; i++) {

        while (i != months) {
            amount = worth;

            worth = amount + amount * percentage / 1200;


        }
    System.out.print(worth);
```

Comment: That's not a complete file.  You are missing tags in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You do not modify neither `i` nor `months` in

```
while (i != months) {
    ....
}
```

so if the `(i != months)` condition is satisfied, the loop runs forever, and you never get to `System.out.print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < months; i++) {

while (i != months) {
//you have to modify i or to modify the while condition.
}
```

**if you don't modify i in the while you can't exit from the loop**

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected code-**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CDValue {
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an amount");
double amount = input.nextInt();

System.out.println ("Enter the annual percentage yield");
double percentage = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println ("Enter the number of months");
int months = input.nextInt();

double worth = amount + amount * percentage / 1200;

for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
{
System.out.print("Month " + i + " = " + worth);
amount = worth;
worth = amount + amount * percentage / 1200;
}
```

**Note:** If you want to print values for each month then the print statement should be inside the loop. You don't need two loops for the objective that you have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been told your code won't get out of the  while loop if you don't modify it. Simply remove the while loop. Your code should be like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CDValue {
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an amount");
double amount = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println ("Enter the annual percentage yield");
double percentage = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println ("Enter the number of months");
int months = input.nextInt();

double worth = amount + amount * percentage / 1200;

for (int i = 1; i < months; i++) {
amount = worth;
worth = amount + amount * percentage / 1200;
}
System.out.print(worth);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Solved it by using 
    {
    System.out.print("Month " + i + " = " + worth);
    amount = worth;
    worth = amount + amount * percentage / 1200;

instead of while loop. 
It works now :) Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome! Please accept the answer which solved your problem so that the question can be closed. Post the same text that you posted here as a comment to that answer rather than posting it as an answer itself.